# why do the bullets still follow player even after being spawned

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I am trying to make a game where the player clicks to shoot upwards at things falling down. The player can move left and right. What I have done is made a bullet prefab with a script that makes the bullet move up when one is instantiated and is destroyed when out of view:

```
public class Bullet_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(transform.position.y >= 6)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also made an empty game object which is where the bullets spawn when the player clicks, it has 2 scripts. Bullet_Shoot.cs, all this does it make it so when the player clicks the bullet gets instantiated:

```
public class Bullet_Shoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bullet;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // And remember to make the bullet disappear after going higher than a certain height
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Shoot1"))
        {
            Instantiate(bullet, transform);
        }
    }
}
```

The other script is where the problem starts, it is Follow_Player.cs, all this does it makes it so when the player moves, so does the bullet spawner. I made this so even if the player moved, bullets would still come out of the player. The problem is that if you shoot a bullet, and it goes up, and then you move to the side, the bullet that is in the air also moves to the side. i want the bullet just to go straight up and not move at all heres the script:

```
public class Follow_Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private float playerX;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        playerX = player.transform.position.x;
        gameObject.transform.position = new(playerX, transform.position.y);
    }
}
```

i tried rearranging some code and trying to fix it in every way i can but nothing worked

Comment: You instantiate bullets as children of the spawner: `Instantiate(bullet, transform)`, so of course when the spawner moves the bullets move. Is there any reason not to make bullets parentless?

Comment: @Verpous i can make them parentless, i never thought of that, how would i do that?

Comment: Just don't use the overload that passes a parent. [There are many to choose from](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) depending on whether you want to provide a starting position and rotation, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in

```
Instantiate(bullet, transform);
```

you make them be spawned as children of the `transform`.

Instead you probably rather want them be spawned on scene root level

```
Instantiate(bullet);
```